# Issue in mysql sums

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries as below which finds average price of a stock per month

query1: average price for a month from 9.30 am to 1.30 pm

query2: average price for a month from 1.30 am to 2.30 pm

I need to divide the differences and price changed percentage

query1

```
--- 9.30 to 1.30 prices ---

select DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d'),sum(price*qty)/sum(qty) 
from trades1
where symbol='GREG.N0000'
and transact_time between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31'
and DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%T') between  '09:30:00' and '13:30:00'
group by DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d')
```

query2

```
--- 1.30 TO 2.30 prices ---

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d'),SUM(price*qty)/SUM(qty) 
FROM trades1
WHERE symbol='GREG.N0000'
AND transact_time BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31'
AND DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%T') BETWEEN  '13:30:00' AND '14:30:00'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d')
```

I need to take the difference of query1's result and query2's result and the price changed percentage. Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT p1 - p2 , p2 /p1 FROM
(select DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d') d1,sum(price*qty)/sum(qty) p1
from trades1
where symbol='GREG.N0000'
and transact_time between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31'
and DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%T') between  '09:30:00' and '13:30:00'
group by DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d')) t1 JOIN
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d') d2,SUM(price*qty)/SUM(qty) p2
FROM trades1
WHERE symbol='GREG.N0000'
AND transact_time BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31'
AND DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%T') BETWEEN  '13:30:00' AND '14:30:00'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(transact_time,'%Y %M %d')) t2 ON t1.d1 = t2.d2
```